# Xpages: How to ensure my cacheBean only loads once

Tags: java, xpages, managed-bean

Still struggling with properly making a cacheBean. I think I want the bean to be a singleton, from what I have read. Will only need 
one instance of it. Use it to get often used keywords and so on.

http://blog.defrog.nl/2013/02/prefered-way-for-referencing-beans-from.html

I used this pattern to make my CacheBean (and used a utility method).

If I make this a managedBean by putting it into Faces-config, then I can easily get the value of models

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"          
value="#{CacheBean.models}"></xp:text>
```

The JSF takes care of instantiating the bean for me.

But I don't want it to reload the same values (like models) over and over. I thought that to get that to happen I needed to make
a POJO and grab the currentInstance of the bean, as in the url.

However, when I made this change (taking the bean out of the faces-config file, I cannot seem to get a handle on the properties.

This won't even compile:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
        value="#{Cache.getCurrentInstance().models}">
    </xp:text>

What am I doing wrong?
```

================================

```
package com.scoular.cache;

import java.io.Serializable;
import org.openntf.domino.xsp.XspOpenLogUtil;

import com.scoular.Utils;

public class CacheBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2665922853615670023L;
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "CacheBean";

    private String pcDataDBpath;

    private Vector<Object> models = new Vector<Object>();


    public CacheBean() {
         initConfigData();
    }

    private void initConfigData() {
        try {
      loadModels();
      loadDBPaths();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }


    // Getters and Setters

    public static CacheBean getInstance(String beanName) {
        return (CacheBean) Utils.getVariableValue(beanName);
    }

    public static CacheBean getInstance() {
        return getInstance(BEAN_NAME);

    }

    public String getPcDataDBpath() {
        return pcDataDBpath;
    }

    public void setPcDataDBpath(String pcDataDBpath) {
        this.pcDataDBpath = pcDataDBpath;
    }

    public void loadDBPaths() {

        Session session = Factory.getSession();
        Database tmpDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();

        pcAppDBpath = (tmpDB.getServer() + "!!" + "scoApps\\PC\\PCApp.nsf");
        pcDataDBpath = (tmpDB.getServer() + "!!" + "scoApps\\PC\\PCData.nsf");
        compDirDBpath = (tmpDB.getServer() + "!!" + "compdir.nsf");
    }

    public void loadModels() {
        try {
            Session session = Factory.getSession();
            Database tmpDB = session.getCurrentDatabase();
            Database PCDataDB = session.getDatabase(tmpDB.getServer(), "scoApps\\PC\\PCData.nsf");
            ViewNavigator vn = PCDataDB.getView("dbLookupModels").createViewNav();
            ViewEntry entry = vn.getFirst();
            while (entry != null) {
                Vector<Object> thisCat = entry.getColumnValues();
                if (entry.isCategory()) {
                    String thisCatString = thisCat.elementAt(0).toString();
                    models.addElement(thisCatString);
                }
                entry = vn.getNextCategory();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            XspOpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }
```

p

```
ackage com.scoular;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class Utils {

      public static Object getVariableValue(String varName) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            return context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, varName);
          }
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're doing with the CacheBean stuff.  If you're just loading filePaths to other .nsf files I'm not sure you need to worry about Singleton stuff here.  You could just have an appScoped bean for something like that.  Since everybody uses the same appScope there should be only 1 instance of the bean object.

Comment: David, I have a lot of other things I am caching that I cut out for simplicity and clarity. I want to be able to get these values throughout the app and only load them once. I think a managed bean using application scope will work? Will it?

Comment: if there are no user specific data in the CacheBean, give it a ApplicationScope, when there are user specific data it should be SessionScope. The runtime will handle the instantiation of the bean. The call in EL will be CacheBean.models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the bean has the right scope you can access the bean directly if is created.

```
private static final String BEAN_NAME = "CacheBean";

//access to the bean
    public static CacheBean get() {
            return (CacheBean) JSFUtil.resolveVariable(BEAN_NAME);
    }

//in my JSFUtil class I have the method
public static Object resolveVariable(String variable) {
        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), variable);
    }
```

so in a Java Class you can call

```
CacheBean.get().models
```

in EL you can use

```
CacheBean.models
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you why it's not compiling at least.

value="#{Cache.getCurrentInstance().models}"

That's EL.  So there should not be a get or a ().  You want

value="#{Cache.currentInstance.models}"

And check your var name as I thought you were using CacheBean and not Cache.